# Dynamic Discount on Products

Tags: e-commerce

In the real world the discount on products you purchase is quite interesting. For example a seller offers a discount on his products in the following way:

- On buying one quantity there will be no discount
- On buying 2 he offers 10% discount
- On buying 4 and 5 disount will be 20%
- On 6 and onward 22%

What is the best way to accomplish this in an eCommerce application?

Comment: I'm thinking that this probably calls for a bunch of `if()` and `else if()` statements.

Comment: Did you tag w/ `genetic-algorithm` ?  GAs wouldn't help here. And quite frankly this is not an algorithm question per se...  It is just a matter of setting up a lookup table with the range of number of items necessary to qualify for a given discount, and to find the corresponding entry when the number of items effectively purchased is known...  The rationale for having a lookup table rather than a switch statement or series of tests is to allow easier changes to the discount scale and also to allow the table to be used for display purposes to incite the user to increase his purchases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a ceiling function of the exponent or approximation thereof. For example Discount = MaxDiscount * (1 - (N-1)/N), where N is number of items. for 1 item discount is 0, for 2 items discount is 1/2 of the max, for large number of item it will approach MaxDiscount. Use ceiling function to you want discount to be integer number.

Comment: So odd solution.By any means it does not make sense. Does it makes sense to divide a number by zero?

Comment: That should have been (N-1)/N, sorry