# deciding discounts on set (which can be multiple) of products

Tags: algorithm

I tried finding this question on SO over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576340/dynamic-discount-on-products) but I dont find it relevant.

Let's say

```
1. Offer1 : buy 3 or more pencil and get 10% discount
2. Offer2 : buy 2 scale and 1 sharpener and get 20% discount on each set
```

so, a cart with `pencil ($10) : 4` , `scale ($20): 5`, `eraser($5): 1` and `sharpener($10): 2` will look like:

```
Pencil : 4 Qty  ==> $36  ($40 with 10% discount)
Scale: 2 Qty + Sharpener : 1 Qty ==> $40 ( $50 with 20% discount)
Scale: 2 Qty + Sharpener : 1 Qty ==> $40 ( $50 with 20% discount)
Eraser: 1 Qty  ==> $5

Cart Total :  $ 121   ( 36 + 40 + 40 + 5)
```

How to go ahead for implementing such algorithm ? Please guide me on this.

Answer (score 0):

It should be a comment, but I don't have enough reputation points..so posting this way..

You can try below -

At the starting you have all the items and their corresponding prices.

1. Now create a method like calculatePrice_set1 which takes no of pencils and per pencil cost as parameters. Calculate total cost, if no of pencil more than 3 then substract discount and return the amount.
2. create another method calculatePrice_set2 which takes no of scale and sharpener and their corresponding cost. Now find how many set of 2 scales you have. Suppose you have passed 6 scales and 4 sharpeners as parameter. Then you have 3 set of 2 scales and 4 sharpeners. From this you can find how many eligible set for Offer2 you can make, which is 3 for this case. Calculate the total price for the set accordingly, apply discount and add left over pieces which couldn't be part of any set.

Then you can add return amount from step 1+ step 2+ (no. of eraser*price)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply but it seems tightly coupled with the sets. For every set you want me to write one function.

Comment: Not set really but offer wise you have to make one function, in this case total 2 functions and a main function... but yeah there might be a better solution, world is of endless possibilities